# StringIndexOutOfBoundException in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

How to avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundException in this code ? I want to get every two characters in the string.

```
String path = input.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++ )
    {
        String n = path.substring(i,i+1);
        String nPlus1 = path.substring(i+1, i+2);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `i < path.length()` needs to change to something different.

Comment: @ZouZou: I'd expect it to give the final character. It's fine for the second argument to be `path.length()`. It's the *second* line of the loop body that's the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oops. Yes the endIndex is exclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the last iteration, `i` will be equal to `path.length() - 1`. Therefore in this statement:

```
String nPlus1 = path.substring(i+1, i+2);
```

... the first argument will be equal to `path.length()`, and the second argument will be equal to `path.length() + 1`. The first argument is valid; the second isn't. As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, **or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object**, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

To fix this, just adjust your loop bounds:

```
for(int i = 0; i < path.length() - 1; i++)
```

(It's not really clear what you mean by "I want to get every two characters in the string" but this will at least not throw an exception.)